# I want to add elements to an array inside of an object

Tags: redux

// its a Reddux reducer I want to add some elements inside of array which is inside of an object.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {funder:[], totalFund=0}
const fundReducer = (fund = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FUND_HELP":
            return {//I dont know How...}
     default :
return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's totally depends on the `payload` here. So what is payload here, You should add it here in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
return INITIAL_STATE.funder.push("some element");
```

Comment: You are mutating the `INITIAL_STATE` here which is not recommended. Redux is totally based on the functional programming principle. It should be a pure function. BTW when you return the `push` result it will give you the new length, not the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to update array, works like **push()**

```
  return {
    ...fund,
    funder: [...fund.funder, action.payload],
  };
```

or you can only add array

```
  return {
    ...fund,
    funder: action.payload,
  };
```

Comment: @Jahidhasan If it worked for you, upvote to so some support ;)

Comment: It totally depends upon the `payload` here. If it is an array object then your code will work fine but what `payload` is `{ propToAdd: { name: "Test", amount: 2300 }}`. Then It won't work at all.

Comment: Second, `state` doesn't exist in the OP code, It should be `fund` and `fund.founder`